# How to put button just after text in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

How to put button just after text in react-native like on image below?

[image: It should look like that:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onPress` prop in `Text` component. And use nested `Text`

You can try here: https://snack.expo.io/@vasylnahuliak/9a76b0

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const handleLinkPress = () => {
    alert('link pressed')
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>
        Short descriptopm for trainer: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore.
        <Text style={styles.link} onPress={handleLinkPress}> edit </Text>
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  link: {
    color: 'blue',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<TouchableOpacity></TouchableOpacity>` for example. You just have to wrap your `<Text>-Tag` in it.

```
<TouchableOpacity> <Text> edit </Text> </TouchableOpacity>
```

TouchableOpacity has OnPress Events similar to a Button.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity

Comment: Can you write example on snack.expo.io? I guess this choice not working, because `TouchableOpacity` will be under text in this case.

Answer (score -2):

You can try with https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-render-html#making-your-custom-component-block-or-inline

Make edit button as an href link and you can get its onPress on onLinkPress prop

Comment: Using html parser for this case is overhead